# mod_rewrite in conjunction with "options indexes"

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a directory ("files") where sub-directories and files are going to be created and stored over time. The directories also need to deliver a directory listing, using "options indexes", but only if a user is authenticated, and authorized. I have that part built, and working, by doing the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/files>
  Options Indexes
  IndexOptions FancyIndexing SuppressHTMLPreamble
  HeaderName /includes/autoindex/auth.php
</Directory>
```

Now I need to take care of file delivery. To force authentication for files, I have built the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule /files/(.*) /auth.php
```

I also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule /files/(.*) /auth.php
```

Both directives are not redirecting to auth.php when I request:

foo.com/files/bar.pdf
foo.com/files/baz/bar.pdf

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/files/(.*) /auth.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
```

- Not sure if this is a problem, but I use `REQUEST_FILENAME` for this and not `REQUEST_URI`
- Make sure Rewrite is enabled with `RewriteEngine on`
- If you want the value of your capture `(.*)` to be passed to your script, you need to tell Apache how/where to pass the value by using a `$1`
- Add a `^` to the beginning of your rule to make sure you're matching `/files/blah.txt` and not, say, `/foo/files/blah.txt`.
- Add the `[NC,L]` to tell Apache to use case-insensitive matching and to stop processing rules on this match.

Comment: I changed REQUEST_URI to REQUEST_FILENAME, added the ^ at the beginning of the regular expression, and I added "[NC,L]" to the end of the rewrite rule. I do not need to pass the requested file on as a query string param, since PHP is able to capture that via it's SERVER superglobal. Still unable to get mod_rewrite to trigger on "foo.com/files/bar/baz.pdf" when using the "-f" flag. If I switch it to "!-d", mod_rewrite triggers for "foo.com/files/bar/baz.pdf" but it also triggers on "foo.com/files/bar/", which I do not want.